# I want to transpose Column values into Row of Specific values like 'GType'(values as rows) as mentioned in the below example

Tags: pivot, cte

Example Table:
[image]

Result Table:
[image]

I want to transpose Column into Rows of Specific Row values like 'GType'(values) as mentioned in the below example. 
I want a results to be in the below example format. I tried doing this using Pivot but I was not able to get result as mentioned in the below example result table. 
Could you please help on this.

Comment: Please tag you DBMS version included, and let me suggest you to take a look at; [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PIVOT for this. You simply self-join the table back to itself multiple times (joining on Parent and GName) and use WHERE clauses to ensure you're joining the correct rows to the respective parent.

See this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ff364362e5591cb8773dd28a9f1ae679) or below code.

```
CREATE TABLE #GValues
(
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    GName VARCHAR(255),
    GType VARCHAR(255),
    Parent VARCHAR(255),
    ParentType VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #GValues (GName, GType, Parent, ParentType)
VALUES
    ('A', 'Domain', 'Top Level', ''),
    ('B', 'Entity', 'A', 'Domain'),
    ('C', 'Sub', 'B', 'Entity'),
    ('D', 'Term', 'C', 'Sub'),
    ('EF', 'Domain', 'Top Level', ''),
    ('GH', 'Entity', 'EF', 'Domain'),
    ('IJ', 'Sub', 'GH', 'Entity'),
    ('KL', 'Term', 'IJ', 'Sub')

SELECT d.ID, d.GName AS [Domain],
    e.ID, e.GName AS [Entity],
    s.ID, s.GName AS [Sub],
    t.ID, t.GName AS [Term]
FROM #GValues d
INNER JOIN #GValues e ON e.Parent = d.GName
INNER JOIN #GValues s ON s.Parent = e.GName
INNER JOIN #GValues t ON t.Parent = s.GName
WHERE d.GType = 'Domain'
    AND e.GType = 'Entity'
    AND s.GType = 'Sub'
    AND t.GType = 'Term'

DROP TABLE #GValues
```